# Solving multiple formulas using recursion

Tags: python, recursion, memoization

I have to use recursion to compute the value of the following formulas:

```
m = 1.4 *t + 1.2*z + 0.8*l + 0.1*o

o = 1.0 *g + 1.3 *g + 1.3 *f + 0.2 *t

t = 0.9*g + 0.9 *f

l = 1.8 *t + 1.7 *g + 0.7 *o
```

With `f= 1.4, z= 1.7, g= 1.9`

I'm not sure how should I proceed into tranforming this into a recursive function.

Comment: You must declare all your variables with the initial values before using it or else it'll give error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from sympy import symbols

f, z, g, m, o, t, l = symbols('f z g m o t l')

f = 1.4
z = 1.7
g= 1.9

t = 0.9*g + 0.9 *f

o = 1.0 *g + 1.3 *g + 1.3 *f + 0.2 *t

l = 1.8 *t + 1.7 *g + 0.7 *o

m = 1.4 *t + 1.2*z + 0.8*l + 0.1*o

print(m)

# 17.53624
```

Comment: Do you know of any other ways to do this without using sympy?